# Colour Detection During Line Following

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a line follower bot which follows black line on white background The code is something like this

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
try:
    while(1):
        ## Read the image
        ret, img = cap.read()
        #cv2.imshow('image',img)
        img = img[160:320,:,:]

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,170,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        #Applying Dilation Morphological Operation To Dilate the image 
        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
        dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations = 5)    
        #Apllying Gaussian Bluring Algorithm to reduce the number of contours
        blur3 = cv2.medianBlur (dilation,5)
        i = 0
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blur3,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
        cv2.imshow('image',img)

        M = cv2.moments(contours[i])
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])


        if cx < 190:                                 
               print "LEFT"
        if cx > 450:
              print "RIGHT "                    
       if ((cx > 189) & (cx < 449)):
              print "FRONT"
finally:
            cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I want to also detect blue and red color while the bot is following the line using the same camera.

I tried reading center pixel of the centroid `center_px = img[cy,cx]`

But reading just one pixel dosent prove efficient in determining the color.

So is there any other approach to do this

I am using python2.7 with cv2

Comment: You determin the centroid anyway, so why not use it? What do you understand by "not efficient"? Nothing in image processing is more efficient than accessing a single pixel. The centroid does not have a central pixel btw.. The centroid usually is a coordinate given in sub-pixel accuracy and it is located between up to 4 pixels.
You can get an intensity/colour value for the centroid through interpolation

Comment: @Piglet I Acceded the bgr value of centroid but this values changes as intensitity of light in the room changes

Comment: How can i make the intensity adoptable

Comment: If you are only interested in the colour it should not be a problem if it becomes brighter or darker as red things will cause higher red values than blue things and vice versa. You could also go with HSI values and check the Hue value to determin if you are above red or blue markers. Intensity changes should not matter then as long as you are not saturated